# inactive break points in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I started using Google Chrome dev tools, but sometimes the break points become inactive and an asterisk appears on the file tab in the debug window. Anyone know why? I guess it is a common behavior, but I want to know how to avoid this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Not sure about chrome, but in most IDE's it means that section of code will _never_ be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've edited the javascript file inside Chrome's inspector.

Chrome let's you edit the javascript right in the browser, but once you've edited the javascript the breakpoints you set will not be hit until you save the edited file (ctrl-s).

You can tell that you've modified the file because of the asterisk next to the name in the tab. i.e. `on_cell_change.js*` - the `*` means the file is edited.

To avoid having this happen at all, don't type inside the javascript source.

Comment: Thanks Matt, what I think it happens is when I click inside the tool  area and start scrolling up and down, sometime break points disappear. However if I save they become active.